# Solr - grab previous/next X amount words from keywords

Tags: regex, search, solr

Is there a way to query for keywords and grab the previous x amount of words and the next x amount of words?

Example

(Searching for "Test")

Aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll Test mm nn oo pp qq rr ss tt…

Where x was 5 would return

“hh ii jj kk ll Test mm nn oo pp qq rr ss”

With “Test” highlighted.

or

(Searching for "Test" AND/OR "Spam")

Aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ii jj kk ll Test mm nn Spam oo pp qq rr ss tt…

Where x was 5 would return

“hh ii jj kk ll Test mm nn Spam oo pp qq rr ss tt”

With “Test” and "Spam" highlighted.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been looking into Regex but I'm quite clueless there. Here are the resources I've been using. Also, my contains $,. and other random punctuation (tried going down the isolate by sentences). Let's just assume spaces to separate.

http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Highlighting#Highlighting-UsingBoundaryScannerswiththeFastVectorHighlighter

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters/

Thanks!

Comment: My problem seems to come from the way I am searching a document. I am dividing it up based on 70 characters (to the nearest world). This sometimes has this results "blah blah blah test1 test2 blah blah..." === "blah blah blah test1" & "test2 blah blah..." which would return 2 snippets. I was thinking of searching by paragraph (GAP - to keep context) and then manually moving the em tags. I'm hoping SO has a more elegant solution

Comment: Or perhaps there is a way to use regex to break the snippets by sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Highlighting tool - it will give you snippets of the matched document with the search terms italicized (in HTML). You can then home in on those markers (`<em>`) and then go backward and forward character by character until you accumulate five space characters.

Comment: Guessing on the frontend I do that?

Comment: Yes that will have to be on the front-end. I believe that would be simpler than writing a plug-in in Java that hooks into Solr :)